# will the webserver [IIS] possibly know whether a request is an AJAX request or a Normal one

Tags: ajax, webserver

will any webserver [IIS possibly] know whether a request is an AJAX request or a Normal one.

Comment: just for learning purposes. According to me any request [ajax / normal] is a request and is there any specific information that a webserver can receive about a request and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for the receiving page to 'know' would be to send a query string parameter.  This isn't 100% safe though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using native XmlHttpRequests then there is no difference between this request and once generated by visiting a page or submitting a form. If you use jQuery to create the AJAX request then is adds a request header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. This header could be used to distinguish AJAX and non-AJAX requests.

Comment: do you agree with david kemp's reply. If yes, then why and if not then too why.. let this be a good discussion which focusses on the serverside aspects.

Comment: @saravanan - I agree 100% with David Kemp. The http request will be the same unless a custom header is added to the AJAX request. I mentioned jQuery specifically as this is a popular library and has been adopted by Microsoft through the Request.IsAjaxRequest within .Net. I assume that you are in a Microsoft environment as you mentioned IIS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am developing in ASP.NET MVC 2. Can you give me more details on what the server does after recognizing `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` and is there any difference in the action it takes.

Comment: IIS does not do anything differently by default. If you wanted to handle the request differently then you have a few options. To handle all AJAX requests the same accross all web applications then you could create a httpModule that checked for the relevant header and performed some action, you would register the module within IIS. If it is all requests within a single application you could register the module in the application. If you just wanted to handle the requests in a particular ActionMethod then you could check within that and treat it accordingly. I'll try to post some examples later.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If you are free, do post some examples as it will help me in having a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Some (most?) frameworks can send a custom header, but, really, an ajax request is just the same as a "normal" request from the point of view of the server.

If you use curl, wget, telnet, or a program you write yourself, then the web server handles the request the same way - at the end of the day, it's all HTTP.

Comment: @Kemp :  Can you give me more details on what the server does after recognizing X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest and is there any difference in the action it takes.

Comment: I think @smirkin has already elaborated on this above, but the server just treats the header as an extra header, and passes it through to the handler (in the case of IIS7, anyway). How the handler processes headers is entire undefined. It's theoretically possible that a handler could see the X-Requested-With: XHR and launch a nuclear bomb at @JonSkeets' house. In practise, most handlers follow the HTTP Protocol (http://j.mp/10wgMq), or implement a REST-style API (http://j.mp/17om9q).

Comment: @kemp : As we have the option to define our own request handling functionality via the HttpModules & HttpHandlers, why do you say that this is `undefined`. Anyways, the server takes all requests and processess them alike is the agreement we have. Also @smirkin has opted to post the examples some time later. may be we can have a chance to get a live example then..

Comment: I mean the behaviour is undefined - maybe unspecified is a better word (too many RFCs!)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug can show you what is being sent to the server from both types of requests, try it out.

Comment: The question is about the server side. Firebug is available in the client side.

Comment: yes, hope you have not understood my question fully. All i need is to know whether the IIS Server knows whether this page request is a normal one or an AJAX one. I have already fiddled using the net tab in the firebug, this will help others too.. good point

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, it is not the webserver that can distinguish, but the server side code might be able to distinguish. If you are talking about ASP.NET and AJAX, then `ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack` can be used to find whether a postback is from AJAX or not.

Comment: @Kemp: Right! As I said, the capability lies on the server side code/framework. IIS itself cannot do it.